# Spring Boot project naming convention

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, package, naming-conventions

While creating a Spring Boot app, I thought some points regarding project name and package name in Spring Initializr. The issues:

1. When creating an app that is used to save and manipulate data, should I use `api` or `app` in the name. For example, while creating an app for saving Book data with CRUD operations, should I use `book-api` or `book-app` for a better naming convention. As the app does not serve data to public, and will be used individually, I think it seems to be better using `book-app`. But not sure (also it has endpoints and it may also be considered as API).
2. In Spring Initializr, when I use `book-app` in the name field, the package name field would be `com.example.book-app`. But if there is not multiple modules, I think there is no need to use `book-app` again in this field. For this reason I use just `com.example` (of course I update the domain properly, it is just for example) in the `Package name` field without name. Is that ok? Or should I always use Group + Name (`com.example.book-app`) as in default format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. API (application programming interface) is a name which refers that the program you are writing provides some kind of functionality others can use, such as a library.
2. You should always include the program name, as to minimize clashes of class names in the class-path.

You should use the `book-app` name as it describes an application, but it's not something mandated.

Comment: Thanks for reply. **#1** But at this point, actually I will share this application on GitHub and actually I do not post it on a live environment. That means, this app won't have a dedicated database and it will be used individually instead of publishing it and let people use it. In this situation, should I still use `-api` in its name rather than `-app` ?

Comment: **#2** But in this case, there is extra package name and it seems verbose under `book-api > src > main > java > com.example.book-app `, again `book-api ` is used second times. Is that ok to add the same name (project name) again as package?

Comment: #1 i still think app is the better nomenclature in this case,
#2 the first `book-api` is the name of the folder in which your project stands, it will not be reflected in the package's name. The second `book-api` should stay.

Comment: **#1** At this point, if I publish the app on web and shared endpoints for users, then would I need to use `-api` in its name rather than `-app` ? I think the critical point in here is publishing the app for public usage, right?

Comment: Not every program providing endpoint is an API. Still, it's up to you.